# Is it possible to enter Germany on a multiple entry Schengen visa issued by, but not yet used for, France?

Tags: visas, schengen, legal

I am a Lebanese citizen and have been issued a multiple entry Schengen visa by the French Embassy. I have not used my visa yet, it is still valid.

Is it possible to enter Germany as my first destination?

Comment: It's possible, but your successful entry is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

yes. you can always say that you are heading to France and that is your final destination.
You could simply book/reserve but not pay, apartment or hotel room somewhere in France so you can have proof that you will go to France.